# CSS: PRE tag making card size bigger than container

Tags: html, css

I have a card, which has a pre tag inside it. The problem is, that due to the pre tag, the size of the card is getting larger than the container and hence I'm getting a horizontal scroll bar on my webpage. What shall I do to make the pre tag scroll If the content size is bigger than card? Just like code snippets on stackoverflow ansers. They never extend out of the page horizontally, you get a horizontal scroll bar within the snippet.

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.card-container {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: auto; height: 300px;
}
pre {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flex-style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="menu"></div>
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
                <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
                <p class="paragraph">
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quaerat earum cum dolore saepe eius dignissimos porro, natus ut omnis maiores deleniti repudiandae distinctio quod? Vero tempore laboriosam maxime quidem accusantium ea qui enim doloremque? Maxime accusantium fuga inventore veniam vero quaerat possimus, id magni consectetur, omnis obcaecati recusandae ipsam.
                </p>
                <pre>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa placeat quia cum, corporis amet quas repellat, nostrum inventore numquam accusamus possimus minima maxime error iusto obcaecati consequuntur fugiat magnam. Temporibus?
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it `<pre>` if you don't want pre's behavior?

Comment: I want it, because I want to add code inside it. Here I just added lorem to make it quick, else there will be actual code in there.

Comment: @MeetShah okay gotcha, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: You saved my day Robo, thank you so much. Btw, where can I learn this white-space concept from?

Comment: It's just one of many CSS properties, I like to read developer.mozilla.org for these things.

Comment: Can I have something which scrolls instead of wraps. And the width is not fixed, it will change as the container resizes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `white-space: pre-wrap` property:

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

It keeps the default behavior of `<pre>`, so multiple spaces are being kept as well as new lines, but if the content is too wide for the parent, it gets wrapped.

Comment: Hey Roho, It's wrapping the content if it's bigger than screen, can I have something that scrolls instead of wraps?

Comment: Yeah, set height and add `overflow-x: auto`.

Comment: The question is, you want to scroll horizontally? Keep in mind that's a bad user experience to have content scrolled horizontally.

Comment: No, just like how stackoverflow does. The code snippets on stackoverflow, if are wider than scree, it will have a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Then just add `overflow-x: auto;`.

Comment: I tried, that's not working, it's still extending out of the container

Comment: And if you also add `width: 100%`?

Comment: No dude, that's not working either. It's stretching out my entire container due to which now I have horizontal scroll on the entire page rather than the code only.

Comment: @MeetShah okay, I tried to experiment a bit, but looks like `<pre>` behaves in a really weird way. The only way it worked for me was with hardcoding the `width`, which is obviously not what is acceptable. Let me know when you find the answer, I'm curious.

Comment: @MeetShah however, when I did my own experiment with flexbox and `<pre>` in it, it worked as expected just by adding the `overflow-x: auto;`.

Comment: In my case, I don't know why but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Text in a "pre" element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed exactly as written in the HTML source code.

If you want to have that effect instead of "pre" tag, put this:

```
          <div
            class="container-outer"
            style="
              overflow: scroll;
              overflow-y: hidden;
              width: 350px;
              height: 210px;
            "
          >
              <div class="container-inner" style="width: 500px">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
                placeat quia cum, corporis amet quas repellat, nostrum inventore
                numquam accusamus possimus minima maxime error iusto obcaecati
                consequuntur fugiat magnam. Temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa placeat quia cum, corporis
                amet quas repellat, nostrum inventore numquam accusamus possimus
                minima maxime error iusto obcaecati consequuntur fugiat magnam.
                Temporibus?
              </div>
          </div>
```

[Referance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-a-div-horizontally-scrollable-using-css/)

Comment: `nowrap` will render everything in one long line, I don't think that's the point.

Comment: Just tried to help, thought that he wants just one line.

Comment: I edited my post, maybe this works for you?

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way Bartosz. Even being able to give an answer is a strong move. Even if it is wrong. Thanks for contributing :)

Comment: The problem here is that the width of the container is not fixed. So I want it to take up the full width, and scroll if it's even longer.

Comment: I don't know if I quite understand it, so you want it to be like above you have with your HTML code, that I can scroll it horizontally? You want same effect?